# Integrate a product of functions with random variables

Tags: numerical-integration

Assume there is a function $ f(x_1, ..., x_n, Y) $ and I seek for the integral following on an area $ [0, 1]^m $:

$$\int\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m,Y_i)\,dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_m$$

where $ Y_i $s are the parameters I generate randomly for each function. The total number of the functions $ n $ is 200 ~ 2000, which means I cannot type directly into Mathematica to calculate the integral value.
Is there some way to realize this kind of integral? Approximate value is acceptable. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Integrate[
 Product[f[x1, x2, x3, RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]], {j, n}], 
 {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}]
```

Test:

```
n=6;
f[xx_, yy_, zz_, ww_] := xx + yy + zz + ww;

Integrate[
 Product[f[x1, x2, x3, RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]]], {j, n}], 
{x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}]
```

(*

163.454

*)

Comment: Interesting!!! Let me have a try

Comment: This can solve half of the question, but then I have the following error during NIntegral: .... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries......